# Can power bi online work with Azure documentDb

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

According to this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/unleashing-insights-from-data-in-documentdb-with-power-bi/ DocumentDB connector is available for both Power Bi online and Power Bi Desktop.

But when I go to Get Data -> Databases in Power Bi online, I do not see any way to connect to Document DB. I can see the connector only in Power Bi Desktop.

Is Document DB supported as data source in Power Bi online? if no, is there any workaround to make it work? I have a requirement to feed schema-less data (located in Azure) to Power Bi online, I'm searching for any way to do it, whether this is Document DB or some other NoSQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to apologize for my initial answer as I completely missed your key issue about utilizing Power BI Online.  Allow me to try to make amends by attempting a more complete and proper answer.

In the case of Power BI Online, because the Power BI-to-DocumentDB connector is currently in beta, it is not available as a data source within Power BI Online under the Get Data section as you noted.  Saying this, you can create a connection to DocumentDB using the Power BI desktop, publish it to Power BI Online, and then refresh it within Power BI Online.  Following the "[Power BI tutorial for DocumentDB: Visualize data using the Power BI connector](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-powerbi-visualize/)" tutorial, here is a screenshot of running the data refresh on PowerBI.com using the credentials to your DocumentDB database.
[image]

Note, there are is already a request on the Power BI Ideas forum to have DocumentDB available directly within Power BI Online - you can read more and vote for it (if appropriate) at: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7160908-documentdb.

Some additional references that may be helpful:

- [Data Refresh in Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-refresh-data/): Here is some additional information about how Data Refresh works in Power BI.
- [Power BI Content Packs](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-for-developers-a-look-back-at-our-developer-isv-ecosystem-efforts-this-year/): For more information on connectors between Power BI and other data sources, please reference Content Packs.

Comment: i think the question is to access docdb directly from powerbi.com. looks like it isn't available and only way is to use the docdb connector available in power bi desktop and publish report to powerbi.com

Comment: @GopiKolla Unfortunately it is not an option for me, I need to use power bi online. Do you know whether it is possible to write custom connectors for PowerBi Online?

Comment: Apologies for missing the original point and thanks correcting @GopiKolla.   As for your second question, let me dig into this and try to get back to you shortly on this.

Answer (score 2):

please allow me to clarify that connectivity to a DocumentDB account via PowerBI.com is actually there.  Currently, the "Get Data" in PowerBI.com only offers data sources with DirectQuery capability.  Please see this [article](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-azure-sql-database-with-direct-connect/#power-bi-desktop-and-directquery) on DirectQuery.  We are working to support DirectQuery in future.  For now, there are two ways to push DocumentDB data to PowerBI.com.  The first method is what Denny has suggested: build the report via PowerBI Desktop and publish the report to PowerBI.com.  The second method is to leverage [PowerBI API](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-walkthrough-push-data/) to connect and push data from a DocumentDB account to PowerBI.com.

Comment: Is there any way I could track the progress on this issue? Workarounds (not sure what method should I choose, I need to try both) will probably work for us now, but we would still like to have a possibility to do it directly in PowerBi online

Comment: Denny has posted some links to tickets on PowerBi, so I guess that answers my question about tracking